# Even padding on navbar links within a fixed width

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar

I'm having some trouble with the navbar on a site I'm working on. I'm trying to make each link have the same padding, and have the navbar take up a fixed width. So far, I've been unable to figure out how to get even padding on all of the links. I'd like to be able to add and remove links as well, and keep the padding even within the same width. The code I have is below. I just used the links you see and kept messing with numbers until it looked about right, but I'd like to be able to change the links without having to guess-and-check the padding again. Any help would be great. I've also been looking for a solution for a couple days and couldn't find one, but if I missed something and this is a duplicate question, I apologize. Thanks.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="navbar-active"><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li ><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li ><a href="registration.php">Registration</a></li>
        <li ><a href="attendees.php">Attendees</a></li>
        <li ><a href="schedule.php">Schedule</a></li>
        <li ><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
        <li ><a href="speakers.php">Speakers</a></li>
        <li ><a href="photos.php">Photos</a></li>
        <li ><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar -->
```

**CSS:**

```
/**
 * Navbar
 */

div.navbar{
  width:1000px;
  background-color: #E15532;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

div.navbar ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.navbar ul li{
  float: left;
}
div.navbar ul li a{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F7F6E2;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: #AF4128;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-color: #AF4128;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: #AF4128;
  padding-left: 16.67188px;
  padding-right: 16.67187px;
  text-align: center;   
}
div.navbar ul li a:hover{
  background-color: #AF4128;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use display `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell`, it's the best solution I can think of. Live demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ck1hbtzq/

```
.navbar {
    display: table;
    width: 1000px;
}

.navbar ul {
    display: table-row;
}

.navbar li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```